# Mouseover event on activex control in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, activex

I have an activeX control to replace with hyperlink. The functionality everything is working fine, but the problem is i am not able to change the mouse pointer when i mouseover on the activex control.

I dont have any control over activex control, because that is third party control.

Is there any way to handle from javascript or css style.

Please reply me with solution, if anyone knows the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Chandra.

Comment: Did you find any trick to achieve it ?